# Raising a dual quaternion to a real number power

Tags: quaternions, dual-numbers

I'm having trouble finding the power of a dual quaternion ($Q=q_r+q_dε$) raised to some real number $n$: $Q^n=(q_r+q_dε)^n=?$
It is known that for a quaternion $q=e^{\vec{u}}=\cos(|\vec{u}|)+\frac{\vec{u}}{|\vec{u}|}\sin(|\vec{u}|)$, its power to a number $n$ would come to be $q^n=e^{n\vec{u}}=\cos(n|\vec{u}|)+\frac{\vec{u}}{|\vec{u}|}\sin(n|\vec{u}|)$. Something similar happens for dual numbers $(a+bε)^n=a^n+nba^{n-1}ε$. However, this is true for numbers whose multiplication is commutative, since for the case $n=2$ we have $(a+bε)^2=a^2+(ab+ba)ε=a^2+2baε$ given that $ab=ba$. Nevertheless, this is not true for quaternions.

Comment: Use the matrix representation, then you can diagonalize it will be clearer and you won't make commutation mistakes

Comment: Arbitrary exponentiation of arbitrary quaternions is not uniquely defined (and hence not uniquely defined for dual quaternions). For instance, what is $(-1)^{1/2}$? There are infinitely many quaternion square roots of $-1$.

Comment: As a reference for the question you could use [Matrix Representation of Dual Quaternions from  Mehdi Jafari, Mücahit Meral and Yusuf Yayli (Section $5$.: *$n$th Roots of Matrices of Dual Quaternions*)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261507636_Matrix_Representation_of_Dual_Quaternions) with $n^{-1} = x$. There you will also find a step-by-step guide for everything. But it is largely based on mtrices and with little analytical derivation.